# JointJs creating custom shapes and specifying their default link

Tags: jointjs

I'm trying to implement my own shape class with ports. However I want the links that these shapes generate to be smooth. Right now, the only way i know to make smooth links is

`link.set('smooth', true)`.

But how do i do that not through code? How do i get smooth links by just dragging?

I extended Link class (`MyLink`) but how do i tell JointJS which Link class to use when i drag on the port?

```
joint.shapes.myclass.Link = joint.dia.Link.extend({

    defaults: {
        type: 'myclass.Link',
        attrs: { '.connection' : { 'stroke-width' :  5 }},
        smooth:true
    }
});
```

Comment: on a totally unrelated note: what is joint.util.deepSupplement ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Links created via the UI by dragging ports are defined in the `defaultLink` property of the paper. It can either be an object in which case it is a link model or a function that returns a link model:

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    defaultLink: new joint.shapes.myclass.Link,
    ...
})
```

or:

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
   defaultLink: function(elementView, magnet) {
       if (aCondition) return new joint.dia.Link;
       else return joint.shapes.myclass.Link;
   }
})
```

The function gives you flexibility in creating different links on the fly depending on what element is underneath or what magnet (SVG element for port) is being dragged.